# Why my SVM-Light could not work properly?

Tags: python, svmlight

What I'm using is from this page:http://svmlight.joachims.org/

Mac OS X (new): http://download.joachims.org/svm_light/current/svm_light_osx.8.4_i7.tar.gz

After installed as the instructions, I jumped into his example: Inductive SVM (documents are on the same page)

```
$ ./svm_learn example1/train.dat example1/model
Scanning examples...done
Reading examples into memory...100..200..300..400..500..600..700..800..900..1000..1100..1200..1300..1400..1500..1600..1700..1800..1900..2000..OK. (2000 examples read)
Setting default regularization parameter C=1.0000
Optimizing........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done. (425 iterations)
Optimization finished (5 misclassified, maxdiff=0.00085).
Runtime in cpu-seconds: 0.07
Number of SV: 878 (including 117 at upper bound)
L1 loss: loss=35.67674
Norm of weight vector: |w|=19.55576
Norm of longest example vector: |x|=1.00000
Estimated VCdim of classifier: VCdim<=383.42791
Computing XiAlpha-estimates...done
Runtime for XiAlpha-estimates in cpu-seconds: 0.00
XiAlpha-estimate of the error: error<=5.85% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
XiAlpha-estimate of the recall: recall=>95.40% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
XiAlpha-estimate of the precision: precision=>93.07% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
Number of kernel evaluations: 45954
Writing model file...done

$ ./svm_classify example1/test.dat example1/model example1/predictions
Reading model...OK. (878 support vectors read)
Classifying test examples..100..200..300..400..500..600..done
Runtime (without IO) in cpu-seconds: 0.00
Accuracy on test set: 97.67% (586 correct, 14 incorrect, 600 total)
Precision/recall on test set: 96.43%/99.00%
```

Did anyone know whether this is what it should be?
If not, how can I fix this to make it work well?

FYI, I am using OSX 10.9 with python 2.7.5.

Comment: @EMS I'm not sure it's correct or not. The docu about test example is on the same webpage. I could not post more than 2 links at my level.

Comment: @TongLiu Seems the software works fine. What is really troubling you?